# Eclipse: Bundle-Localization loading from xml instead of properties

Tags: xml, eclipse, localization, utf-8, properties

i try to add localisation to my application, but whenever i try to customize a language which needs UTF-8 i get stuck due saving properties as iso.
thats why i was searching for loading those properties from .xml rather than .properties
by now i failed.

any ideas how to solve this problem??

Answer (score 0):

What Eclipse are you using?, because:

- [bug 260997](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=260997) and [bug 310330](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=310330) both reported the need for multiple encoding support,
- [3.6 Editor changes](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.6-201006080911/eclipse-news-part1.html#Text) reports having a "Better handling of unmappable characters on save" on all editors:

[image: Save Problems dialog]

---

Just to be complete, 3.7M5 and 4.1M5 (just [released two days ago, January 2011, 27h](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/S-3.7M5-201101272034/eclipse-news-M5.html)), includes a new option:

#### Store the encoding of derived resources separately

> You can now store encodings of derived resources in a separate preferences file.
>   Usually the encodings for all files in each project are stored in one preference file. If you are using a version control system and the preferences file is shared, the encodings for all resources are shared along with it.
>   This new option allows you to avoid sharing encoding information for derived files, which are not typically shared in a version control system.
>
> If you want to store encoding settings of derived resources separately, go to `Project > Properties > Resource` and select `the Store the encoding of derived resources` separately option.

[image: separate derived encoding preferences]

Comment: i am usingVersion: Helios Service Release 1
Build id: 20100917-0705 

edit: i found an editor on the marketplace which converts any special chars to unicode, which works fine as all my files and code is utf-8 encoded

Comment: @lumo: interesting, does that plugin solve your particular issue? And, if yes, what is its name/address web?